# Python adding values to a dictionary: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to write a code that will take in json values from Kafka and output them to a .csv file. The issue is that, for grades, the values have either science and math OR just english as nested objects.

This is what the data looks like:

> {'id': 0, 'name': 'Susan', 'lastName': 'Johnsan', 'grades': {'science':
>   78, 'math': 89}}
>
> {'id': 1, 'name': 'Mary', 'lastName': 'Davids', 'grades': {'english':
>   85}}

However when I run my code I  keep getting the error TypeError: string indices must be integers.

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import json
import csv
import sys
from datetime import datetime
import os

# connect to kafka topic
kaf = KafkaConsumer('students.all.events')


outputfile = 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\students_output.csv'

outfile = open(outputfile, mode='w', newline='')
master_key = ['id', 'name', 'lastName', 'science', 'math', 'english']

writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, master_key, delimiter="|")
writer.writeheader()
'''
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(['JSON_Data'])
'''

i = 1
for row in kaf:
    if i < 5000:
        json_row = json.loads(row.value)
        print('Row: ', i)
        print(json_row)

        dict = {'id': json_row['id'], 'name': json_row['name'], 'lastName': json_row['lastName']}

        for value in json_row['grades']:
            if value['science'] is not None:
                dict['science'] = value['science']
                dict['math'] = value['math']

            elif value['english'] is not None:
                dict['english'] = value['english']

        writer.writerow(dict)
        i += 1
    else:
        break

outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if the **value** variable is actually of type dict, because the error you get, in general, means that you are trying to access a **string** object in a **dict[key]** way.

Comment: It should be type dict since 'grades' is a nested dictionary:  'grades': {'science': 78, 'math': 89}

Comment: It actually is of type string (you can check it by `print(type(value))`) , you can do something like this `for key, value in json_row['grades'].items()` otherwise you just get the **keys** of the subdicts

Comment: You will have to adjust your logic accordingly with something like this : inside the for loop `dict[key] = value` this will remove the needs of if statements as well

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a typo - at least in the code that you pasted here. There is an extra double quote after the `lastName` key.

Answer (score 0):

Based off of the help @TenorFlyy gave me, I changed my code to fix the issue:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import json
import csv
import sys
from datetime import datetime
import os

# connect to kafka topic
kaf = KafkaConsumer('students.all.events')


outputfile = 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\students_output.csv'

outfile = open(outputfile, mode='w', newline='')
master_key = ['id', 'name', 'lastName', 'science', 'math', 'english']

writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, master_key, delimiter="|")
writer.writeheader()
'''
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(['JSON_Data'])
'''

i = 1
for row in kaf:
    if i < 5000:
        json_row = json.loads(row.value)
        print('Row: ', i)
        print(json_row)

        dict = {'id': json_row['id'], 'name': json_row['name'], 'lastName': json_row['lastName']}

        for key, value in json_row['grades'].items():
            dict[key] = value

        writer.writerow(dict)
        i += 1
    else:
        break

outfile.close()
```